# Flutter app running on web failing with error

Tags: flutter

**/C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_messaging_web-2.2.8/lib/src/internals.dart:11:10: Error: Method not found: 'guardWebExceptions'. return internals.guardWebExceptions( ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I'm update flutter  to

> **[version sdk 2.10.3]**

[1](https://docs.flutter.dev/get-started/install/windows) , if you have error

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).